# App is approved but not showing in App Store iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, app-store-connect

I have uploaded my first version of iOS App to the iTunesConnect on 26th September 2014, today i have got my App Status "Ready For Sale" with green dot. But the problem is if i am tapping on "View On App Store" section of iTunes Connect, then it is successfully showing my app to the App Store. I am getting problem when i have searched this App on App Store, but i am not getting my app over there (NO RESULTS FOR "MY-APP").

I don't have any idea for the same problem, i think i will have mistake on my App Price Tab. Can you please guide me how can i automatically live my app on App Store?

here is the screenshots for your reference :

[image]

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Your availability date was only yesterday it can take up to 24 hours for it to actually appear in the App Store so give it time and it will be there. If I remember rightly my first app took two days before I found it

Comment: Thanks @Popeye Now i have changed Price tier, now i am getting my App after tapping on "View On App Store" section, please check my updated question and suggest me.

Comment: Like i say just leave it 24-48 hours and it will appear there don't worry if you go changing the settings now it could delay it even longer.

Comment: Is this any other solution for my problem instead of waiting 24-48 hours, bcos i need to give reason to my management and i dont have :(

Comment: No there is no way to get Apple to speed things up just for you. Just tell your management it is in there it just takes time for the Apple servers to refresh. I know management can be a pain but if you just tell them that you are waiting on Apple to refresh their servers and it is out of your control it's not like they can punish you for that they will just need to suck it up and accept it.

Comment: yeah correct.. Thanks alot for one of the best reason!!